# article pagination class splits divs and messes up page layout

Tags: css, class, pagination, html

the class works by exploding the content wherever it finds [next]. but the problem is that next is wrapped in divs, so it becomes `<div>[next]</div>`, this because im using a wysiwyg editor. when it find [next] on the first page, the `</div>` after it gets carried over to the second page and so forth, obstructing the layout.

so the class to expode the text:

```
function splitText($pageCont){ 
        $this->textarray = explode('[next]', $pageCont);
        $this->numPages = count($this->textarray); 
    }
```

and the class to echo the blocks of text

```
function getContent(){ 
        if($this->page != 0){ 
        echo $this->pageCont;  
        } else { 
        echo $this->textarray[0]; 
        } 
    }
```

the question is, how can I either stop this from happening, or make it so that the divs within the main div does not affect the page layout? as if now when the divs spit it pushes the right column to the right bottom

the full code with the edit by kuh-chan

```
class Pagebreak { 

    private $page; //page number 
    private $numPages; //number of total pages 
    private $textarray = array(); // array of conents 
    private $pageCont; //current page content 

    public function __construct(){  
        if (!isset($_GET['page'])) { 
        $this->page = 0; 
        } else {
        $this->page = $_GET['page'];  
        }      
    } 

    public function splitText($pageCont){  
        $this->textarray = preg_split('/(?<!\<div\>)\[next\]/', $pageCont);
        $this->numPages = count($this->textarray); 
    } 

    public function setPage(){ 
        $this->pageCont = $this->textarray[$_GET['page'] -1]; 
    } 

    public function getContent(){ 
        if($this->page != 0){ 
        echo $this->pageCont;  
        } else { 
        echo $this->textarray[0]; 
        } 
    } 

    public function getPageLinks(){ 

        echo "<p class=\"article_page_div\">\n";     

        //prev page 
        //if page number is more then 1 show previous link 
        if ($this->page > 1) { 
            $prevpage = $this->page - 1; 
            echo "<a class=\"article_paging\" href=\"?post=".$_GET['post']."&amp;page=$prevpage\">". 'Prev</a> '; 
        }  

        //page numbers   
        for($i = 1; $i <= $this->numPages ; $i++){ 
            if($this->numPages > 1){ // if more then 1 page show links 
                if(($this->page) == $i){ //if page number is equal page number in loop don't link it 
                    echo "$i\n "; 
                    } else {                     
                            if($this->page == 0){ //if no page numbers have been clicked don't link first page link 
                                if($i == 1){ 
                                    echo "$i\n "; 
                                } else { // link the rest 
                                    echo "<a class=\"article_paging\" href=\"?post=".$_GET['post']."&amp;page=$i\">$i</a>\n "; 
                                }  
                           } else { // link pages 
                                echo "<a class=\"article_paging\" href=\"?post=".$_GET['post']."&amp;page=$i\">$i</a>\n "; 
                            }                          
                    } 
            }              
        } 

        //next page 
        //if page number is less then the total number of pages show next link 
        if ($this->page <= $this->numPages - 1) { 
            if($this->page == 0){ //if no page numbers have been clicked minus 2 from the next page link 
                $nextpage = $this->page + 2; 
            } else { 
                $nextpage = $this->page + 1; 
                } 
                echo "<a class=\"article_paging\" href=\"?post=".$_GET['post']."&amp;page=$nextpage\">". 'Next</a>'; 
        } 

        echo "</p>\n";     

    } 

}
```

then to call this class you just use:

```
$paginate = new Pagebreak(); 
$paginate->splitText($storyCont); 
$paginate->setPage(); 
$paginate->getContent(); 
$paginate->getPageLinks();
```

Comment: try preg_split with a negative lookahead

Comment: aahhaa!! getting closer.... how would you write the expression for that function though?    `$this->textarray = preg_split("function", $pageCont);`    because '[next]' is not working

Comment: I actually had split() instead of explode at first but I got  The function split() is deprecated which is why I had changed to explode.

Comment: something like preg_split("/(?<!\<div\>)\[next\]/",$pageCont)

Comment: I just tried that expression and it made like 600 something pages, even when I took the [next] out the article completely... im assuming its making a new page for every single div, not sure

Comment: `preg_split("/(?<!\<div\>)\[next\]/",$pageCont)`
Sorry, there were too few backslashes

Comment: nope, now its doing the same thing the original code did :(  , let me add the full code maybe im missing something somwhere...

Answer (score 1):

> the question is, how can I either stop this from happening, or make it so that the divs within the main div does not affect the page layout? as if now when the divs spit it pushes the right column to the right bottom

Use one of the following CSS properties to remove the divs from the page flow:

- position: absolute
- position: fixed

Use the following CSS property to use the main div as the container of the positioned divs:

- position: relative